# Ruby on Rails - Logging users in and out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've designed the following Helper class to work with logging in and logging out users based primarily on information I've found in tutorials online, though I've run into an error.

```
module SessionHelper

    def login(user)
        session[:user] = user.id
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by( session[:user] )
    end

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def logout
        session.delete(:user)
        @current_user = nil
    end

end
```

When I call the "logout" method, the @current_user session variable does not get destroyed.  In one view, I have the following code written.

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <div class="login">
        Welcome back, <a href="#">@<%= @current_user %></a>!
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Even though my user gets logged out, the  still is displayed and the @current_user is displayed as "#".

I'm just curious if anyone may be able to offer any assistance on this for me.  If so, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use `link_to` helper instead of `href`? Another thing that feels not so right is your call to `logout` helper method. Since it is not obvious how you are calling it, I would suggest to use `method: :delete`, which means that the get request is made delete request by javascript in Ruby on Rails.

So, if I was in your shoes, it would be:

```
Welcome back 
<%= link_to current_user, "#" %>
```

No `<a href>` and `</a>`.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I will be sure to implement that change to the view.  This is the first project I'm working on with Ruby on Rails, so I am happy to hear all suggestions like this.

I'm still quite confused about why @current_user = nil is creating a strange value, such as "#<User:0x49824f0>"

Comment: This is the representation of User's object in Rails. I guess you would like to show user's name (or email). Then you should state: `link_to current_user.name, "#"` (or `current_user.email` respectively).

Comment: Oh I get that, but the issue isn't how I'm displaying the variable in the view (though I do appreciate and will implement your suggestion).  The issue is the value held within the variable after trying to set the value to "nil".  It does not pass a check in the "logged_in?" method after it's set to nil, and I output the value in the section that you've referenced just to try to find out what is in the variable instead of "nil" when it doesn't pass the "nil" check.